# Well, i have a solution for my problem which is how many binary operator are in discrete mathematics, but is this correct?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

So my solution is that there are how many you want, cuz if that operator is defined and doesnt have the same truth statements or table as the four basic operators like ∨,∧,⇒,⇐⇒ then there is a finite number of those right? I mean they all can be simplifed to ∨ and ¬, but if we are asking how many are there in total? You cannot say an exact number or so i think?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You list logical operators, so apparently you mean binary logical operators.  A binary operator has two inputs and if its a logical operator, each input can only have one of two values, so there are only four possible combinations of input.  Each of those has one of two possible outputs.  So how many ways are there to assign two possible values to each of four outputs?

Comment: See [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_connective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_connective#Redundancy): "There are sixteen Boolean functions associating the input truth values P and Q with four-digit binary outputs. These correspond to possible choices of binary logical connectives for classical logic. Different implementations of classical logic can choose different functionally complete subsets of connectives."